# Only able to fix rclone certificate error over ethernet (it won't work over wifi) Why?

Tags: networking, rsync, certificates, synchronization, rclone

rclone will run fine for months at a time. The command I run most often is:

```
rclone sync {{path/to/file_or_directory}} {{remote_name}}:{{path/to/directory}}
```

Then - *seemingly out of nowhere* - I run my `rclone sync ...` command and get the following error:

```
failed to open source object: certificate has expired or is not yet valid
```

I always do the same thing, issue the following commands, and the problem usually goes away:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
```

Occasionally running those three commands above does not work, and I'm forced to take drastic actions:

1. Disable wifi
2. Connect to a router through an ethernet cable
3. Restart the computer
4. retry all of the commands above (upgrade, reinstall ca-certificates, rclone sync *)

and somehow the ethernet connection fixes everything.

**Why do I occasionally have to use an ethernet cable to make my rclone certificate errors go away?** I don't always carry an ethernet cable on me, and even if I did it's not always easy to connect to the router that is offering you wifi access. I do not really know the root cause of the problem, and how to fix it.

Comment: Can't see the relation. What I would do is figure out what is the url  rclone is using and retrieve the certificate with `openssl s_client ...` whenever (and een before) this happens and compare with before, during, and after the problem.

Comment: Does that happen with `rsync` as well?